# OpenGL glFramebufferRenderbuffer() get error: GL_INVALID_OPERATION, status: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm trying to do texture rendering using cocos2d and openGL.

After I called

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBufffer)
```

I checked the status, using:

```
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

and turned out the status was `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`

I also checked the error using

```
GLenum error = glGetError();
```

and the result was `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

According to [the documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferRenderbuffer.xml) the cause of `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is because:

- the default framebuffer object name 0 is bound.
  or
- if renderbuffer is neither 0 nor the name of an existing renderbuffer object

I checked the framebuffer and renderbuffer, neither of them are 0, but I am not sure wheather there is any other rederbuffer object has the same name.

Does any one know how to fix this issue?

The detailed code I was using:

```
.....

GLint oldRBO;
glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_BINDING, &oldRBO);

 // generate FBO
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _FBO);

// associate texture with FBO
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture.name, 0);

if (depthStencilFormat != 0) {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBufffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBufffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencilFormat, (GLsizei)powW, (GLsizei)powH);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBufffer);
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);        // the status here will result in GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
    GLenum error = glGetError ();                // the error here will be GL_INVALID_OPERATION

    // I checked the value of _FBO, which was 1, and the value of _depthRenderBufffer was 2

    .....
}
```

Comment: What value does `depthStencilFormat` have? You should pass `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` to `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` if the render buffer has `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` as its base internal format.

Comment: Thanks GuyRT. I did the following after I check the error:           if (depthStencilFormat == GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8){
   glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBufffer);  }. But before this is called, I already got an error as I described earlier.

Comment: That should be `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` not `GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`

Comment: Thanks, GuyRT. Currently, I am using OpenGL ES 2, and I don't have GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, which is introduced in OpenGL ES 3. And the error is before I did glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBufffer); So I guess the problem is not here.

Comment: So what **is** the value of `depthStencilFormat` used with the posted code? I don't see that clearly answered in the discussion above.